# Stop and restart a already running thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The Thread should end if I press a button, which sets the isButtonPressed to true.
My problem is, that if a want to start the thread with thread.start(runnable) by clicking the button, I get this: *IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already* started (I thought the thread was terminated after the break because the the loop is over, but it seems that I am wrong).

```
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start(runnable);
```

The runnable Runnable:

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        time = 10;
        for (int i = 10; i <= 10; i--) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    txt_Time.setText(String.valueOf(time));
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            if (isButtonPressed) {
                break;
            }

            if (time == 0) {
                resetVisibleState();
                break;
            } else {
                time--;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding to Andrew answer, use executor service instead of restarting a new thread. Have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398144/multiple-newsinglethreadexecutor-vs-newfixedthreadpool-of-executorservice/36404133#36404133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java threads are not restartable. For what you are trying to achieve, you could create a new thread each time, or you could look at an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Just create a single threaded executor ([Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor())), and submit your runnable to it every time you need it to run.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.submit(runnable);
```

Comment: u r great. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Take a boolean variable and wrap the contents you need to run continusly in the thread with a while loop that runs forever till Run is set to false then on clicking the button set the variable to false, for example :-

```
volatile boolean run = true;
Thread t = new Thread()
{
   while(run)
   {
     // whatever is here runs till Run is false
   }
}
t.start();

/*now when the button is pressed just trigger Run as false and the thread will be ended
later call t.start() when you need to start the thread again.*/
```

Comment: While this probably is a valid answer to the question, it would be advisable to declare `run` as `volatile boolean`. When the thread starts running, it will cache the flag from the surrounding scope. As far as I know, it is completely OS dependent when the value will actually be refreshed and it might be a long time.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need to start a new thread. You cannot re-start a thread that has ran its course.

Since you are correctly stopping the old one via your `isButtonPressed`. You should just be able to start a new instance of the thread in its place