# Multiple newSingleThreadExecutor vs. newFixedThreadPool of ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

In my application I have 4 distinct processes, which run permanently with some small pauses.

The current version of code executes each process in a separate old-school thread:

```java
Thread nlpAnalyzer = new Thread(() -> {

    // infine lop for auto restore in case of crash
    //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
    while (true) {
        try {
            // this method should run permanently, pauses implemented internally
            NLPAnalyzer.analyzeNLP(dbCollection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

nlpAnalyzer.setName("im_nlpAnalyzer");
nlpAnalyzer.start();
```

Now I would like to refactor this code with use of `ExecutorService`. In order to do that I can use at least two approaches:

- `newFixedThreadPool(numOfProc)`;
- `numOfProc * newSingleThreadExecutor()`.

My questions:

1. Is there any reason why I should prefer one option over another?
2. What is more accepted to generate a thread pool with X threads or generate X `newSingleThreadExecutor`s?
3. Pro et contra of each of the approach?

Comment: Option 1 is more common and has least overhead.

Comment: On another note, You can re-write the code inside infinite loop as a `Runnable` that posts itself again on as executor service, when run. That way, multiple tasks can run even on a single thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given each task is a infinite loop, what I would used is a

```
newCachedThreadPool();
```

This would create a thread for every task which needed it (and no more)

The benefit of using a single threaded pool each is you could shutdown the pool individually, or give each thread a name, but if you don't need this, it's just overhead.

Note: you can change the name of a thread with setName("My task") which might be useful for debugging/profiling purposes.

One of the tricks of using an ExecutorService is that it captures any uncaught exception/errors and places it in the `Future` object returned.  Often this `Future` is discarded which means that if your task dies unexpectedly it might also do it silently.

I suggest you do a try/catch(Throwable) outside the loop and log it so you can see if the thread ever dies unexpectedly. e.g OutOfMemoryError

Comment: As far as I know, I can assign a separate thread name even into `newFixedThreadPool`, not only with `newSingleThreadExecutor`. Is there any performance difference between define 1 `newFixedThreadPool` for X threads or X `newSingleThreadExecutor`s?

Comment: @MikeB. You can assign a separate thread name, but not one based on the purpose of the task which might be more useful.  I would do whatever you feel is clearer, no matter which solution you chose, a `Thread` still does the work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any benefit for below option except shutting down individual executor.

```
numOfProc * newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

But you have more options. I prefer one of below three options from `Executors`.

```
newFixedThreadPool
newCachedThreadPool
newWorkStealingPool
```

Refer to below SE questions for relevant queries :

[Java's Fork/Join vs ExecutorService - when to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156599/javas-fork-join-vs-executorservice-when-to-use-which/34922218#34922218)

[How to properly use Java Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596079/how-to-properly-use-java-executor/33596230#33596230)

[Difference between Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) and Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300924/difference-between-executors-newfixedthreadpool1-and-executors-newsinglethread)